# Ocaml reading line by line

Tags: ocaml

So i have this ocaml code :

```ml
let read_file file_name = "/home/test.txt" in
  let in_channel = open_in file_name in 
  try 
    while true do
      let line = input_line in_channel in 
    print_endline line
    done
  with End_of_file ->
     close_in in_channel

let my_fun()=
  let f = "test1.ml" in
    read_file f

;;

my_fun ()
```

But it is printing only the 1st line of the file

Can you help me out ?

Answer (score 0):

Your code shows an error along the lines of "unbound value file_name" on line 2. I just turned `read_file` into a function, and called it with the path to the file:

```
let read_file file_name =
  let in_channel = open_in file_name in 
  try 
    while true do
      let line = input_line in_channel in 
    print_endline line
    done
  with End_of_file ->
     close_in in_channel

let my_fun() =
  let f = "home/test.txt" in
    read_file f;;

my_fun()
```

Calling `$ ocaml <filename.ml>` on the file with this code prints each line from the file in the specified path to stdout.

---

**Edit**: Adding some more details on file structure and how to execute:

I have a directory named `sample-dir` with the following contents:

```
sample-dir
   ├── home
   │   └── test.txt
   └── sample.ml
```

The code is in `sample.ml`, the `test.txt` is in the sub-directory called `home`. The contents of `test.txt` are as follows:

```
one
two
three
```

I `cd` into `sample-dir` and execute the following command:

```
$ ocaml sample.ml
```

I get the following output:

```
one
two
three
```

Comment: Got this error :  $ ocaml <efa.ml>
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'

Comment: The angled brackets don't go in the command. Try `ocaml efa.ml`